# Layer buttons on top of images on Google Site

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am creating a dashboard on Google Sites for work. I have a picture of a floorplan on the site with different areas numbered on the picture. I would like to layer buttons on top of the picture so that when you click "1" it takes you to area 1 etc.

Google sites is very limited so I am not sure if this is possible with HTML or not, but I also do not know how to try as I don't know HTML very well

Comment: The feature that you are referencing is the HTML `Image Map element` [Doc ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)

Comment: Have you read [Image areas not turning into clickable area in Image Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32419354/1330560) on StackOverflow, or [imagemap](https://sites.google.com/view/test-links-in-document/imagemap) (external site) or [this post](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/2463456/i-would-like-to-add-an-image-map-so-that-users-can-follow-links-to-specific-urls-i-have-code-but-can-t-figure-out-how-to-add-it-to-a-google-site-page?hl=en) from "Sites Help".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image Map Element https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Follow link to tutorial and follow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).